# Swift JSON Parsing with SwiftyJSONAccelerator

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, object

I want to parse this JSON

```
{"success":true,"timestamp":1523403184,"base":"EUR","date":"2018-04-11","rates":{"AED":4.540671,"AFN":86.176964,"ALL":128.832708,"AMD":595.029101,"ANG":2.200839,"AOA":267.813784,"ARS":24.89115,"AUD":1.592116,"AWG":2.200789,"AZN":2.101261,"BAM":1.958947,"BBD":2.472797}}
```

i used SwiftyJSONAccelerator and program give me 2 files.

```
    //
//  MoneyClass.swift
//
//  Copyright (c) . All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

public final class MoneyClass: NSCoding {

  // MARK: Declaration for string constants to be used to decode and also serialize.
  private struct SerializationKeys {
    static let base = "base"
    static let date = "date"
    static let timestamp = "timestamp"
    static let rates = "rates"
    static let success = "success"
  }


......
```

and second file

```
    //
//  Rates.swift
//
//  Copyright (c) . All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

public final class Rates: NSCoding {

  // MARK: Declaration for string constants to be used to decode and also serialize.
  private struct SerializationKeys {
    static let xAF = "XAF"
    static let rON = "RON"
    static let mYR = "MYR"
  ......
```

and i want parse this json file for tableview. but i cant understand how it can be possible. please help me. 
is there a any tutorial about this subject?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: The question make little sense as-is .. you parse JSON and populate custom entities with the content. Now you need to creates cells and populate them with the values from the entities.

Comment: @blld thanks for your reply. but i can't parse that values can you explain to me?

Comment: To parse JSON have a look here: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

Comment: @blld thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question illustrates why the use of a good tool may sometimes lead to bad results if the circumstances are not matching the intended use. Generating badly capitalised constants for `SerializationKeys` really looks like a code smell and it is. It really pays of to learn about the `Codable` protocol, since it is the right solution for this problem. You will end up with something like this:

```
import Cocoa

struct Rates : Codable {
    let success:Bool
    let timestamp:Int
    let base:String
    let date:String
    let rates:[String:Double]
}

let string = """
{
  "success":true,
  "timestamp":1523403184,
  "base":"EUR",
  "date":"2018-04-11",
  "rates":{
    "AED":4.540671,"AFN":86.176964,"ALL":128.832708,"AMD":595.029101,"ANG":2.200839,
    "AOA":267.813784,"ARS":24.89115,"AUD":1.592116,"AWG":2.200789,"AZN":2.101261,
    "BAM":1.958947,"BBD":2.472797
  }
}
"""
let jsonData = string.data(using: .utf8)!
let decodr = JSONDecoder()
let result = try! decodr.decode(Rates.self, from: jsonData)

if result.success {
    print("got \(result.rates.count) rates from JSON")
    print("Thre rate of AUD against \(result.base) is \(result.rates["AUD"]!)")
}
```

This way your data is way more manageable, even if you have to deal with the inherently optional nature of a `Dictionary` (which is hard to avoid unless you *really* are able to determine all the keys ever to be returned from your interface which seems a tall order).

Designing the `struct` to be used as your data holder will require you to think about your data and since in this case the `keys` of your `rates` Dictionary will probably be considered "Data" they should be modelled accordingly. Probably not the only way to describe your JSON-data, but the easiest one I could see right away.

Btw: Do us a favour next time you post a long string and break it into lines meaningfully, otherwise it is just hard to read (and tripple quoted `String` constants are just great anyways :-).